openapi-fetch - wrap the client to process response
we are working on a Typescript project on Node.js and we are using openapi-fetch to do HTTP requests against our schemas.
We are using it to build a group of SDKs, each one will have its own openapi-fetch client to do requests for a specific schema.
Basic example of our usage
import type { paths } from "./schema.js";
....
this.client = createClient<paths>({
      baseUrl: process.env.BACKEND_URL,
    });
const response = await this.client.GET("/hello", params);


The SDKs will inherit from a base one.
We want to format the response of all the request we make, like
const response = await formatResult(this.client.GET("/hello", params));

So we thought to wrap the methods to then directly use them
// T is paths, so the schema used to create the client
public async GET(
    url: PathsWithMethod<T, "get">,
    params: any,
  ) {
    return this.client.GET(url, params);
  }

Problem: we want to use the correct type on params, so to have the correct check  on the valid parameters during transpilation, but we didn't find a valid way to do that.
Did somebody already tried to achieve this?
